# Prism Modules having its own Regions in View

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism-4

i'm practicing in Prism V4.1 with Silverlight 5 (MefBootstrapper). Unfortunately I can't find implementation of situation like this:

1. I have 2 Regions in my Shell.xaml.
2. My modules(xap files described in modulescatalog.xaml)(Module1 and Module2) are injected in this regions;
3. One of my views in module(Module1 for example) has it's own regions.

And I'd like to use power of prism framework to inject another modules to this Module1 View. In fact this module should be a little prism application with it's own modules which should have possibilities to pass params to Module2 and others.

Is there any way to implement this?

I mean: can view inside the Module1 create its own Region, so dependent module can inject view into this Region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can, why not? Just register the views with this region after a dependent module is loaded. For instance, you can do it in the `IModule.Initialize` method of the dependent module:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Module1RegionName", () => serviceLocator.GetInstance<DependentModuleView>());
}
```

Then you can navigate to this view or activate it whenever you want as soon as it is registered.

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("Module1RegionName", new Uri("DependentModuleView", UriKind.Relative));

//or resolve the view and activate it
var view = serviceLocator.GetInstance<DependentModuleView>();
var region = regionManager.Regions["Module1RegionName"];
region.Activate(view);
```

As for the communication between modules you have a few options. Read [Communicating Between Loosely Coupled Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: ,thank you for help. But i'm getting an error when i'm trying to resolve Views.

This code in IModule.Initialize throws exception:
`ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoaderTabView>();`

Exception:
Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LoaderTabView, key ""

View class:
`[Export("LoaderTabView")]
    public partial class LoaderTabView : UserControl`

Comment: I've found my mistake.I should use `[Export] public partial class LoaderTabView : UserControl` instead of `[Export("LoaderTabView")] public partial class LoaderTabView : UserControl`

Comment: @Grigory I'm glad you figured this out.